# How to increase and resize css doc menu panel image after clicking..?

Tags: css

I am having css3 dock menu panel which contain 8 images.If click on particular image, I want to increase it's size/change background color, vise-versa while clicking on another image previous image should be re-size or background color remove....how can I do this..?

Answer (score 1):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ShEdE/)

***HTML***

```
<a href="#zoom1"><img id="zoom1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#zoom2"><img id="zoom2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#zoom3"><img id="zoom3" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="" /></a>
```

***CSS***

```css
#zoom1,
#zoom2,
#zoom3 {
    background: #e3e3e3; 
    display: block; 
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 100px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}

#zoom1:target,
#zoom2:target,
#zoom3:target {
    background: #555;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try js if you can

```
<script>
document.getElementById("wantedelement").attribute_size="newvalue"; 
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp